# How to connect to Openfire server with a client in python?

Tags: python, server, client, xmpp, openfire

Can you please suggest a client library for connection to Openfire server?
What do you think is a better client library for development in python (XMPPPY,PyXMPP, SleekXMPP or any other you may suggest)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best library depends on your use case, try SleekXMPP following the examples [here](https://sleekxmpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#here-s-your-first-sleekxmpp-bot). You may also want try [aioxmpp](https://docs.zombofant.net/aioxmpp/devel/user-guide/quickstart.html#connect-to-an-xmpp-server-with-jid-and-password) which provides easy to use APIs. Or you can just try start from simple examples like [this](https://leonjza.github.io/blog/2013/05/25/how-to-extremely-simple-python-jabber-broadcast-bot/) using xmpp and build on it.

My suggestion is try these clients, go with whichever does the job for what you want to achieve. I would prefer **SleekXMPP** just because I tried it and it did the job for what I wanted it for, it also has a better documentation and many examples. But aioxmpp is also something I would like to try.